# Почему не сразу прогружается js-код?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть скрипт, обычные часы, выглядят он вот так:

```js
setInterval(function(){
    date = new Date(),
    h = date.getHours(),
    m = date.getMinutes(),
    h = (h < 10) ? '0' + h : h,
    m = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m,
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ':' + m;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="time">00:00</span>
```

На странице он прогружается с задержкой ну 1-1.5 секунды.
Как мне исправить мою проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Твой `setInterval` запускает функцию только после 1 секунды. а т.е. не сразу

```js
const updateTime=()=>{
    const date = new Date();
    let h = date.getHours();
    let m = date.getMinutes();
    h = (h < 10) ? '0' + h : h,
    m = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m,
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ':' + m;
};

setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
updateTime();
```

```html
<span id="time">00:00</span>
```

Comment: Этот скрипт работает также, как мой, с такой же задержкой.

Comment: @АндрейКоломиец ты уверен что ты его подключил? как ты его подключаешь? зачем ты его выбрал как ответ, лул

Comment: Он работает чуть быстрее, подключаю файлом <script src="script.js"></script>

Comment: @АндрейКоломиец в body или head? Попробуй в head и `window.onload=()=>{ /* здесь 2 ласт строки js файла */ };`

Comment: В body после span указывал

Comment: Да, вот теперь моментально всё, спасибо.